# error installing SDK - Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK Setup Wizard ended prematurely

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Trying to setup Service Fabric on local machine. Installed the Azure Service Fabric runtime version 10.0.1816.9590. Trying to install the Azure Service Fabric SDK 7.0.1816 msi. Keep getting the error on the setup wizard: "Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK Setup Wizard ended prematurely". What is causing this error? How/Where can I find out what is causing this error?

I didn't see any logs. Tried running the msi from powershell as administrator. Checked the registry that service fabric runtime was installed and the registry key, FabricVersion, has the correct version that was installed.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. I managed to create a logfile during installation and is get the following error:

> SFXCA: Binding to CLR version v4.0.30319 Calling custom action
> SdkRuntimeCompatibilityCheck!Microsoft.ServiceFabric.SdkRuntimeCompatibilityCheck.CompatibilityCheckCA.CheckWithRuntimeCA
> Error: could not load custom action class
> Microsoft.ServiceFabric.SdkRuntimeCompatibilityCheck.CompatibilityCheckCA
> from assembly: SdkRuntimeCompatibilityCheck
> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'SdkRuntimeCompatibilityCheck, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Strong
> name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A) File
> name: 'SdkRuntimeCompatibilityCheck, Version=10.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' --->
> System.Security.SecurityException: Strong name validation failed.
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)

Comment: Thank you for the description of the error. That greatly helped! Searching for SdkRuntimeCompatibilityCheck, I found the following article, https://github.com/microsoft/service-fabric/issues/1462, and was able to resolve the problem. I ended up using Chocolatey to do the installation following the Powershell command in the article.